# Problem displaying shopping cart items using cookies in a React and Express application

Tags: reactjs

I have a web application where users can add items to their shopping cart. I use React for the frontend and Express for the backend. When a user adds an item to the basket for the first time, a cookie containing the basket ID is created, valid for 24 hours. The problem I'm experiencing is that items added to the basket are not displayed correctly on the basket page.

**Here's what I've already done**:

- I configured the Express server to create a cookie with the basket ID when the user adds an item.
- I set up an Axios request in React to retrieve the cart ID from the cookie.
- I tried to filter products by cart ID to display them in the cart.

**Problem**:
The items are not displayed correctly in the shopping cart, even though I use the cart ID to filter the products. I'm sure the cookie is created correctly because I get the cart ID, but something is wrong with the display of the items.
The Cart Component React

```
/** @format */

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { isEmpty } from "../../Components/Utils";
import TotalPrice from "../../Components/TotalPrice";
import axios from "axios";
import { getCart } from "../../actions/cart.action";
import EmptyCart from "../../Components/EmptyCart";
const Cart = () => {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cartReducer);
  const products = useSelector((state) => state.productsReducer);
  const carts = useSelector((state) => state.cartsReducer);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log(cart);
  const [cartId, setCartId] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCartToken = async () => {
      await axios({
        method: "get",
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}cartId`,
        withCredentials: true,
      })
        .then((res) => {
          setCartId(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log("Le panier est vide!"));
    };
    fetchCartToken();
    if (cartId) dispatch(getCart(cartId));
  }, [dispatch, cartId]);
  console.log(cartId);

  return (
    <div>
      <header className="header">
        <div className="header__topbar">
          <Link to="/">
            <p className="header__topbar__logo">Panini</p>
          </Link>
          <div className="header__cart__desktop">
            <span className="header__topbar__cart__value"></span>
            <Link to="/panier" className="header__topbar__cart__icon">
              Mon panier
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="cart__header">
          <Link to="/" className="cart__back-icon"></Link>
          <h1 className="header__insight">Mon Panier</h1>
        </div>
      </header>
      <main className="main">
        <section>
          {cart !== null ? (
            <>
              {" "}
              <hgroup className="cart__details">
                <h3>Produits</h3>
                <h4>Quantités</h4>
                <h5>Prix</h5>
                <div>#</div>
              </hgroup>
              <article className="cart__container">
                {!isEmpty(products[0]) &&
                  products.map((product) => {
                    for (let i = 0; carts.length; i++) {
                      if (
                        cart === carts[i].cartId &&
                        product.id === carts[i].productId
                      ) {
                        return (
                          <div key={product.id} className="cart__items">
                            <div className="cart__items__product">
                              <div className="cart__items__product__img">
                                <img
                                  src={product.product_image}
                                  alt="produit ajouter au panier"
                                />
                              </div>
                              <div className="cart__items__product__infos">
                                <p>{product.name}</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="cart__items__quantity">
                              <div className="cart__items__quantity__container">
                                <button
                                  className="cart__items__quantity__minus-btn"
                                  id="minus"
                                >
                                  -
                                </button>
                                <span className="cart__items__quantity__product">
                                  {cart.quantity}
                                </span>
                                <button
                                  className="cart__items__quantity__plus-btn"
                                  id="plus"
                                >
                                  +
                                </button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="cart__items__price__infos">
                              <p>{product.price}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="cart__items__delete">
                              <span className="cart__items__delete__btn"></span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        );
                      }
                      return null;
                    }
                  })}
                <TotalPrice cartId={cart} />
                <div className="cart__items__next">
                  <Link to="/contact" className="cart__items__next__btn">
                    Continuer
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </article>
            </>
          ) : (
            <EmptyCart />
          )}
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

Backend server:js

```
/** @format */

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");

//Routes dependences
const adminRoutes = require("./routes/admin.routes");
const categoryRoutes = require("./routes/category.routes");
const productRoutes = require("./routes/product.routes");
const optionRoutes = require("./routes/option.routes");
const cartRoutes = require("./routes/cart.routes");
const orderRoutes = require("./routes/order.routes");

const app = express();

require("dotenv").config("./.env");

//Dependencies server
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
const corsOptions = {
  origin: process.env.FRONT_URL,
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: ["sessionId", "Content-Type"],
  exposedHeaders: ["sessionId"],
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  preflightContinue: false,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

const { requireAuth, checkCart } = require("./middleware/auth.middleware");

//Get cart cookies
app.get("/cartId", checkCart, (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).json(res.locals.cart.id);
});
//Jwt ROUTES
app.get("/jwtid", requireAuth, (req, res) => {
  return res.json(res.locals.admin.id);
});

//Routes
//Admins Routes
app.use("/api/admin", adminRoutes);

app.use("/uploads", express.static(path.join("uploads")));
//Global Routes
app.use("/api/categories", categoryRoutes);
app.use("/api/categories", productRoutes);
app.use("/api/products", productRoutes);
app.use("/api/cart", cartRoutes);
app.use("/api/cart", orderRoutes);

//Strating Server
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listenning on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

Cart action redux

```
/** @format */

import axios from "axios";

export const GET_CART = "GET_CART";

export const getCart = (id) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    return await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/cart/${id}`,
      withCredentials: true,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({ type: GET_CART, payload: res.data });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
};
```

cart controllers

```
const models = require("../models");

const { Product, Option, Cart, OrderItem } = models;

const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const maxAge = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 24h

const createToken = (id) => {
  return jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.CART_TOKEN, {
    expiresIn: maxAge,
  });
};

//Create a cart
module.exports.addToCart = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.cookies.cart;

    const { productId, optionId, quantity } = req.body;
    const product = await Product.findByPk(productId);

    let option;

    if (optionId !== undefined) {
      option = req.body.optionId;
    }
    const isFound = await OrderItem.findOne({
      where: { productId: product.id },
    });

    //Check if item has already been added to cart
    if (isFound)
      return res
        .status(401)
        .json(`${product.name} a déjà été ajouter au panier`);

    if (!token) {
      const cart = await Cart.create({});
      cart.save();

      const sessionToken = createToken(cart.id);
      res.cookie("cart", sessionToken, { httpOnly: true, maxAge });
      if (cart) {
        const createOrder = await OrderItem.create({
          CartId: cart.id,
          productId,
          quantity,
          optionId: option,
        });
        return res
          .status(201)
          .json({ order: createOrder.toJSON(), sessionToken });
      }
    } else {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.CART_TOKEN);
      const cartId = decoded.id;
      const cardExisting = await Cart.findByPk(cartId);

      if (cardExisting) {
        const addOrder = await OrderItem.create({
          CartId: cartId,
          productId,
          quantity,
          optionId: option,
        });
        return res.status(201).json(addOrder.toJSON());
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};
//Get all cart
module.exports.getCarts = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const allCartItems = await OrderItem.findAll({
      order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
    });
    return res.send(allCartItems);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
};
//Get cart by cartId
module.exports.getCart = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    console.log(id);
    const cart = await OrderItem.findOne({ where: { cartId: id } });
    console.log(cart);
    if (cart.cartId) {
      const cartByCartId = await OrderItem.findAll({
        where: {
          cartId: cart.cartId,
        },
        order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
      });
      return res.status(200).json(cartByCartId);
    } else {
      return res.status(404).json("Ce produit n'est pas disponible");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};
```

**Question** :

1. How can I ensure that items are correctly associated with the server-side basket ID?
2. Are there any obvious errors in the React code I shared for displaying the cart based on the cart ID?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!